# Como dividir uma linha de ficheiro sem usar Substrings em C#?

Tags: c#, arquivo, datagridview

Eu criei um ficheiro em que guardo linha a linha dados como `morada|nome|telefone|nif`, ou seja, cada variável guardada no ficheiro está dividida por `|`.

Lembro-me de haver um método de dividir esta linha em 4 para adicionar a uma dataGridView sem usar Substrings ou IndexOf... Há alguma maneira mais rápida de ser feito?

Por exemplo, quero adicionar `morada` a uma coluna, `nome` a outra e etc...

Comment: E por que não usar `Substring()`? Quer fazer como?

Answer (score 5):

Que tal o método `Split` ?

```
string s = "morada|nome|telefone|nif";
string[] colunas = s.Split('|');
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", colunas[0], colunas[1], colunas[2], colunas[3]);
```

> Exemplo funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/LhI6/1)

#### Referência

- [Método Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx)